# Improving performance on an alphanumeric text search query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table where millions of records are there I'm just posting sample data. Actually I'm looking to get only Endorsement data by using **LIKE or LEFT** but there is no difference between them in Execution time. IS there any fine way to get data in less time while dealing with Alphanumeric Data. I have 4.4M records in table. Suggest me

```
declare @t table (val varchar(50))

insert into @t(val)values 
('0-1AB11BC11yerw123Endorsement'),
('0-1AB114578Endorsement'),
('0-1BC11BC11yerw122553Endorsement'),
('0-1AB11BC11yerw123newBusiness'),
('0-1AB114578newBusiness'),
('0-1BC11BC11yerw122553newBusiness'),
('0-1AB11BC11yerw123Renewal'),
('0-1AB114578Renewal'),
('0-1BC11BC11yerw122553Renewal')



SELECT   * FROM @t  where RIGHT(val,11) = 'Endorsement'

 SELECT  * FROM @t  where val like  '%Endorsement%'
```

Comment: Your second query doesn't look too far off.  What result set does that give you?

Comment: both are giving same results while coming to execution both are showing equal time. Is there any other way to get good performance @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Using `LIKE` should perform worse than taking a substring and comparing IMO.  Have you benchmarked both queries using very large tables?

Comment: yes I have executed both the queries with large data set in my environment and more often I haven't find any much of difference @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Use `FULL TEXT INDEX`

Comment: @VR46 can you please tell me how to implement Full Text Index as I have never heard of such thing

Comment: @mohan111 - start here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you'd have to find names in a telephone book that end with a certain string. All you could do is read *every single name* and compare. It doesn't help you at all to see where the names with A, B, C, etc. start, because you are not interested in the initial characters of the names but only in the last characters instead. Well, the only thing you could do to speed this up is ask some friends to help you and each person scans a range of pages only. In a DBMS it is the same. The DBMS performs a full  table scan and does this parallelized if possible.

If however you had a telephone book listing the words backwards, so you'd see which words *end* with A, B, C, etc., that sure would help. In SQL Server: Create a computed column on the reverse string:

```
alter table t add reverse_val as reverse(val);
```

And add an index:

```
create index idx_reverse_val on t(reverse_val);
```

Then query the string with LIKE. The DBMS should notice that it can use the index for speeding up the search process.

```
select * from t where reverse_val like reverse('Endorsement') + '%';
```

Having said this, it seems strange that you are interested in the end of your strings at all. In a good database you store atomic information, e.g. you would not store a person's name and birthdate in the same column ('John Miller 12.12.2000'), but in separate columns instead. Sure, it *does* happen that you store names and want to look for names starting with, ending with, containing substrings, but this is a rare thing after all. Check your column and think about whether its content should be separate columns instead. If you had the string ('Endorsement', 'Renewal', etc.) in a separate column, this would *really* speed up the lookup, because all you'd have to do is ask `where val = 'Endorsement'` and with an index on that column this is a super-simple task for the DBMS.

Comment: yeah I will implement this and let you know but here I'm taking all the results in temp table because this data is coming from different tables through multiple joins

Comment: It is quite common for data to stem from multiple tables. This doesn't necessarily mean you need a temporary table. I would use temporary tables only if I worked on the data iteratively or had to access the results again and again.

Answer (score 1):

try charindex or patindex:

```
SELECT *
FROM @t t
WHERE CHARINDEX('endorsement', t.val) > 0


SELECT *
FROM @t t
WHERE PATINDEX('%endorsement%', t.val) > 0
```

Comment: this is taking much more time

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE  TABLE tbl 
(val varchar(50));

insert into tbl(val)values 
('0-1AB11BC11yerw123Endorsement'),
('0-1AB114578Endorsement'),
('0-1BC11BC11yerw122553Endorsement'),
('0-1AB11BC11yerw123newBusiness'),
('0-1AB114578newBusiness'),
('0-1BC11BC11yerw122553newBusiness'),
('0-1AB11BC11yerw123Renewal'),
('0-1AB114578Renewal'),
('0-1BC11BC11yerw122553Renewal');


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX inx
ON dbo.tbl(val) 


 SELECT  * FROM tbl  where val like  '%Endorsement';
--LIKE '%Endorsement' will give better performance it will utilize the index well efficiently than RIGHT(val,ll)
```